# How to test components using new react router hooks?

Tags: react-router

Until now, in unit tests, react router match params were retrieved as props of component.
So testing a component considering some specific match, with specific url parameters, was easy : we just had to precise router match's props as we want when rendering the component in test (I'm using enzyme library for this purpose).

I really enjoy new hooks for retrieving routing stuff, but I didn't find examples about how to simulate a react router match in unit testing, with new react router hooks ?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

**Edit**: The *proper* way of doing this the way described in Catalina Astengo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58206121/917750) as it uses the real router functionality with just the history/routing state mocked rather than mocking the entire hook.

The way I ended up solving it was by mocking the hooks in my tests using jest.mock:

```js
// TeamPage.test.js
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'), // use actual for all non-hook parts
  useParams: () => ({
    companyId: 'company-id1',
    teamId: 'team-id1',
  }),
  useRouteMatch: () => ({ url: '/company/company-id1/team/team-id1' }),
}));
```

I use `jest.requireActual` to use the real parts of react-router-dom for everything except the hooks I'm interested in mocking.

Comment: Works like a charm, and this pattern will be usefull for many cases in my project to mock precises points of external modules without breaking everything :)

Comment: I never knew about `jest.requireActual` this is greatly helping !

Comment: what if i have to pass different companyId in same test file

Comment: If you need different params for each test in a test suite I would recommend using spyOn as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61665964/2201223

Comment: This answer lead me astray for a bit, the next-highest voted answer (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/58206121/344405] is the "blessed" way of getting the component into a state where the URL contains the params you are looking for, without the need to mock.

Answer (score 133):

I looked at the tests for hooks in the `react-router` [repo](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/__tests__/useParams-test.tsx) and it looks like you have to wrap your component inside a `MemoryRouter` and `Route`. I ended up doing something like this to make my tests work:

```js
import {Route, MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

...

const renderWithRouter = ({children}) => (
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['blogs/1']}>
      <Route path='blogs/:blogId'>
        {children}
      </Route>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
)
```

Comment: The problem is mocking the new `react-router-dom` hooks. Wrapping your component in a MemoryRouter is definitely what you want to do though for any component under test that is within a router. There are numerous patterns for creating a reusable wrapper such as https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router

Comment: Router V6<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/blogs/1']}><Routes><Route path="/blogs/:blogId" element={<PostScreen />} /></Routes> </MemoryRouter>

Comment: gives this error: `A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>`

Comment: @ChumiestBucket look at the comment above your own. Version 6 was not available at the time of the answr.

Comment: Does it not work with HistoryRouter?

Answer (score 37):

In your component use hooks as below

```js
import {useLocation} from 'react-router';

const location = useLocation()
```

In your test spy on reactRouter Object as below

```js
import routeData from 'react-router';

const mockLocation = {
  pathname: '/welcome',
  hash: '',
  search: '',
  state: ''
}
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(routeData, 'useLocation').mockReturnValue(mockLocation)
});
```

Comment: nice one, the above help by using spyOn Thanks @suchin

Comment: Thanks! It works! how did you learn about `routeData`? I can't find it in the react-router docs.

Comment: Thanks small syntax correction:

`beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(routeData, 'useLocation').mockReturnValue(mockLocation)
  });`

Comment: @GundamMeister the name doesn't matter since is the default export from 'react-router's

Comment: I used this to mock useParams hook, other methods didn't work for me.

Comment: this eventually worked for me, except I needed:
import * as routeData from 'react-router';

Comment: You need to add `key` to mockLocation as `Location` has changed.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `react-testing-library` for testing, you can get this mock to work like so.

```js
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useLocation: () => ({ state: { email: 'school@edu.ng' } }),
}));

export const withReduxNRouter = (
    ui,
    { store = createStore(rootReducer, {}) } = {},
    {
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [ route ] }),
    } = {}
) => {
    return {
    ...render(
        <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>{ui}</Router>
        </Provider>
    ),
    history,
    store,
    };
};
```

You should have mocked `react-router-dom` before it has been used to render your component.
I'm exploring ways to make this reusable

Comment: I was testing a basic ionic app that used the useLocation hook. This worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: if you used CRA to create your project you could just put the jest.mock block into setupTests.js(ts)

Comment: Hello @chidimo, did you find a way to make this reusable?

Comment: I think I did. I made a post which you can find here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/07/react-apps-testing-library/

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to get if the `push` function in `useHistory` is called by doing that but I can't get the mocked function calls...

```
const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useHistory: () => ({
      push: mockHistoryPush,
    }),
  }));

fireEvent.click(getByRole('button'));
expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/help');
```

It says that `mockHistoryPush` is not called when the button has `onClick={() => history.push('/help')}`

Comment: jest mocks hoist the mocked module before anything else, thus your `mockHistoryPush` won't be seen at runtime. Instead, within your test, do something like `import * as ReactRouterDom from 'react-router-dom'; jest.spyOn(ReactRouterDom, 'useHistory').returnValue({
    push: mockHistoryPush,
  })`

Comment: @JensBodal I just tried that and got an  "TypeError: Cannot set property useHistory of [object Object] which has only a getter", will update if I find a solution

Comment: Any news on that @JasonRogers ? :'(

Comment: I'm having the same issue currently. Seems impossible to mock / test this situation.

Comment: Mocking history.push is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524183/how-to-mock-history-push-with-the-new-react-router-hooks-using-jest

Answer (score 2):

For those using [vitest](https://vitest.dev/), the mock will look something like this:

```js
vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => {
  const actual = (await vi.importActual('react-router-dom')) as object
  return {
    ...actual,
    useParams: () => ({
      id: '204444'
    }),
    useRouteMatch: () => ({ url: '/deputy/204444' })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My  use case was unit testing a custom hook using using useLocation(). I had to override the inner properties of useLocation which was read-only.

```js
\\ foo.ts

export const useFoo = () => {

   const {pathname} = useLocation();


\\ other logic

return ({
          \\ returns whatever thing here
       });
}

/*----------------------------------*/

\\ foo.test.ts

\\ other imports here

import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router';


Object.defineProperty(ReactRouter, 'useLocation', {
   value: jest.fn(),
   configurable: true,
   writable: true,
});

describe("useFoo", () => {


       it(' should do stgh that involves calling useLocation', () => {

           const mockLocation = {
               pathname: '/path',
               state: {},
               key: '',
               search: '',
               hash: ''
           };


         const useLocationSpy =  jest.spyOn(ReactRouter, 'useLocation').mockReturnValue(mockLocation)



          const {result} = renderHook(() => useFoo());
         
           expect(useLocationSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();


       });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of the above solutions which **includes several params and query strings for a more complex scenario**. This is easy to abstract into a utility function similar to a few above which can be reused by other tests.

short version

```js
      <MemoryRouter
        initialEntries={[
          '/operations/integrations/trello?business=freelance&businessId=1&pageId=1&pageName=Trello',
        ]}
      >
        <Route path="/operations/:operation/:location">
          <OperationPage />
        </Route>
      </MemoryRouter>
```

Longer version:

The example snippets below include a full example of the test file, component and logs to help leave little room for interpretation.

includes:

- react 16
- redux 7
- react-router-dom 5
- typescript
- thunk
- sagas
- @testing-library/react 11

`operations.spec.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import createDebounce from 'redux-debounced'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import rootReducer from 'redux/reducers/rootReducer'
import OperationPage from '../operation'
import { initialState } from '../mock'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom' // can be moved to a single setup file

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const middlewares = [thunk, sagaMiddleware, createDebounce()]
const composeEnhancers = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  // any type only until all reducers are given a type
  initialState as any,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
)

const Wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>

describe('Operation Page - Route', () => {
  it('should load', async () => {

    const Element = () => (
      <MemoryRouter
        initialEntries={[
          '/operations/integrations/trello?business=freelance&businessId=1&pageId=1&pageName=Trello',
        ]}
      >
        <Route path="/operations/:operation/:location">
          <OperationPage />
        </Route>
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
    render(<Element />, { wrapper: Wrapper })
    // logs out the DOM for further testing
    screen.debug()
  })
})
```

logs and the component via `operations.tsx`. Got lazy including the all types (via typescript) for this component but outside of scope :)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import queryString from 'query-string'

const OperationPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { search } = useLocation()
  const queryStringsObject = queryString.parse(search)
  const { operation, location } = useParams<{ operation: string; location: string }>()

  console.log(
    '>>>>>queryStringsObject',
    queryStringsObject,
    '\n search:',
    search,
    '\n operation:',
    operation,
    '\n location:',
    location
  )
  return <div>component</div>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    test: state.test,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(OperationPage)
```

terminal where the tests are running

```sh
>>>>>queryStringsObject [Object: null prototype] {
  business: 'freelance',
  businessId: '1',
  pageId: '1',
  pageName: 'Trello'
}
 search: ?business=freelance&businessId=1&pageId=1&pageName=Trello
 operation: integrations
 location: trello


 PASS  src/__tests__/operations.spec.tsx
  Operation Page - Route
    ✓ should load (48 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       0 skipped, 1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.365 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Mock useSearchParams

```
const searchParams = { "name": "test"};
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as object),
  useSearchParams: () => [searchParams]
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

If using the `enzyme` library, I found a much less verbose way to solve the problem (using this section from the `react-router-dom` [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing)):

```js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './Navbar'

it('renders Navbar component', () => {
  expect(
    shallow(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Navbar />
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
  ).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```