# How to mock history.push with the new React Router Hooks using Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock `history.push` inside the new `useHistory` hook on `react-router` and using `@testing-library/react`. I just mocked the module like the first answer here: [How to test components using new react router hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117890/how-to-test-components-using-new-react-router-hooks)

So I am doing:

```
//NotFound.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


const RouteNotFound = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.push('/help')} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RouteNotFound;
```

```js
//NotFound.test.js
describe('RouteNotFound', () => {
  it('Redirects to correct URL on click', () => {
    const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();

    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
      useHistory: () => ({
        push: mockHistoryPush,
      }),
    }));

    const { getByRole } = render(
        <MemoryRouter>
          <RouteNotFound />
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    fireEvent.click(getByRole('button'));
    expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/help');
  });
})
```

But `mockHistoryPush` is not called... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You actually do not need to mock `react-router-dom` (at least for v5) as it provides a bunch of testing tools: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing

To check your history is actually changed, you can use `createMemoryHistory` and inspect its content:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { Menu } from './Menu';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

test('triggers path change', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();

  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Menu />
    </Router>
  );

  const aboutItem = screen.getByText('About');
  expect(aboutItem).toBeInTheDocument();

  userEvent.click(aboutItem);
  expect(history.length).toBe(2);
  expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/about');
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Mocking react-router can cause unnecessary complexity.

Comment: The link is changed. Please update if possible.

Comment: any idea how in RR6?

Comment: @ChumiestBucket I assume you should use `MemoryRouter`: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/memory-router

You have a test sample on this documentation page.

Comment: @Hubert, but this approach won't be an option if you use `MemoryRouter`. `MemoryRouter`  allows you to set the initial path (`initialEntries`) while `Router` doesn't. I totally agree that mocking react-router-dom is often complex though

Comment: I am trying out this solution but I always get `element type is invalid: Expected a string (for built-in components) or a class / function (for composite components) but got: undefined`. There are nothing wrong with my imports so I'm confused and wondering anyone else faced this issue as well? My `react-router-dom` version is `5.2.0`

Answer (score 109):

Use `jest.mock` in module scope will automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block. So that you can get the mocked version `react-router-dom` in `NotFound.jsx` file and your test file.

Besides, we only want to mock `useHistory` hook, so we should use `jest.requireActual()` to get the original module and keep other methods as the original version.

Here is the solution:

`NotFound.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const RouteNotFound = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.push('/help')} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RouteNotFound;
```

`NotFound.test.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import RouteNotFound from './NotFound';

const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockHistoryPush,
  }),
}));

describe('RouteNotFound', () => {
  it('Redirects to correct URL on click', () => {
    const { getByRole } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <RouteNotFound />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    fireEvent.click(getByRole('button'));
    expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/help');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/58524183/NotFound.test.jsx
  RouteNotFound
    ✓ Redirects to correct URL on click (66ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 NotFound.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.133s, estimated 11s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58524183

Comment: @slidershowp2 can you please help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928263/how-to-write-test-case-for-url-push-in-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: Hey @slideshowp2, thanks for this answer. I was trying to do this but I had the `jest.mock` inside of the `describe` block and it wasn't working. Do you know why this is the case? I found this thread but I still don't understand it. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582

Comment: You saved me. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm having the same issue expect my component using `RouteComponentProps`along with the `useHIstory()` hook. The hook returns undefined with the components inside the test. Is there a solution for mocking `useHistory()` with a component that uses `RouteComponentProps`?

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you have created File method in Order.JSx to execute a click event.
If you check i am using
**const history = useHistory();**

```
This is react functional component 
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
        function ReactOrders({ prams }) {
        const history = useHistory();
    
        const viewOrder = (order) => {
            **history.push({**
                pathname: `/order/${order.orderId}/${order.orderCompany}/${order.orderType}`,
            });
        };
    
        const renderOrder = (order, index) => {
            return (           
                    <div className="view-order">                   
  <button className="button button-secondary" onClick={() => viewOrder(order)}>
                                View Order
                            </button>
                        </div>              
               
            );
        };
```

Now in OrdersTest.js

```
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

let history = createMemoryHistory();

let mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({   
    useHistory: () => ({
        push: mockHistoryPush
    }),
})); 

 describe("and it returns multiple orders", () => {    
             
                beforeEach(() => {                     
                    _component = shallow(                     
                            <Orders {...props} orders={_orderData.salesOrderHeader} fetching={false} />
                        , {
                        context: { router: history }, // Provide the mock history object as context
                    });                  
                });
       
                fit("shows a link to the order details", () => {                  
                    _component.find(".details .view-order .button")
                        .forEach((b, i) => {
                            b.simulate("click");
                        });                
                    expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ "pathname": "/order/orderBert/company1/CO" });
                    expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ "pathname": "/order/jobbert/company2/SO" });
                });
      
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there with `react-router-dom` V4, [this](https://dev.to/ilumin/test-history-in-react-router-17f5) worked for me:

```js
    // HomeButton.test.jsx
    import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
    import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
    
    import { HomeButton } from './HomeButton';
    
    describe('HomeButton', () => {
      // the test might throw an error about required properties, it's depend on your component's dependencies.
      const mockHistory = {
        push: jest.fn(),
      }
    
      it('should go to home after click', () => {
        await act(async () => {
          render(
            <Router history={mockHistory}>
              <HomeButton />
            </Router>
          )
    
          userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('button'))
        })
    
        expect(mockHistory.push).toBeCalledTimes(1)
        expect(mockHistory.push).toBeCalledWith("/home")
      })
    })
```

Answer (score -3):

This may be helpful. You can use **jest.fn()** to mock history.push().

```
const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() }   

expect(historyMock.push.mock.calls[0]).toEqual([
        {
          pathname: "/profile", // URL
          search: , // search-data
        },
      ]);
```