# Jest function call for functional component gives error on stimulate click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have imported a table component in a different component file and I am passing props form the parent component.

TableWrapper.js

```
const handleRowClick = rowData => {
 // function data
}

<TableRender onRowClick={handleRowClick} id={'AUDIT'} />
```

I am writing test cases for this kind of function as I want this function to be covered and pass the data to it `rowData`

testFile.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('handle row click is called', () => {  
    const handleRowClick = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<TableWrapper {...props} onRowClick={handleRowClick} />);
    const rowClickFunction = wrapper.find('.ra--audit-table__content');
    rowClickFunction.simulate('handleRowClick');
    expect(handleRowClick).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

If I do this then it passes the test case but does not cover the function in coverage.

testFile.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('handle row click is called', () => {  
    const handleRowClick = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<TableWrapper {...props} onRowClick={handleRowClick} />);
    const rowClickFunction = wrapper.find('.ra--audit-table__content');
    rowClickFunction.simulate('handleRowClick');
    expect(rowClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
```

If I do this change it gives me an error:-

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

I want this function to b covered.
Any Idea for this?

Comment: Why was it tagged with react-testing-library if you use Enzyme? Considering you're using shallow, you may want to test TableRender in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are simulating wrong event. you should simulate `click`.

change:

```
const rowClickFunction = wrapper.find('.ra--audit-table__content');
rowClickFunction.simulate('handleRowClick');
```

to:

```
const elem = wrapper.find('.ra--audit-table__content');
elem.simulate('click');
```

(also make sure the clickable element has a `.ra--audit-table__content` class)

2. you are creating wrong component. you should create a `TableRender`, not `TableWrapper`.

change:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<TableWrapper {...props} onRowClick={handleRowClick} />);
```

to:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<TableRender onRowClick={handleRowClick} />);
```

Code (`testFile.js`) :

```
it('handle row click is called', () => {
    const handleRowClick = jest.fn((i) => {console.log(`row ${i} clicked`)});
    const wrapper = shallow(<TableRender onRowClick={handleRowClick} />);
    const elem = wrapper.find('.ra--audit-table__content');
    elem.simulate('click');
    // expect(handleRowClick).toBeTruthy();
    expect(handleRowClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
```

Ps: i tested it and it works fine.

Comment: can you please help me in this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519179/testing-api-with-next-js-in-jest