# Why does useParams during test return undefined in test env with wrapper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I have seen this in 2 different code bases now and am stumped because it works fine in the actual browser but not the tests:  if a component uses the `useParams` hook, the hook throws an error in the test:

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot destructure property `accountId` of 'undefined' or 'null'.]

I am using React Functional Component, React Testing Library and React-Router:

// component:

```
const Overview: FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location) // see below
  const { accountId } = useParams();
  console.log(accountId) // see below

  ... rest
}
```

the console logs appear to have found the params properly:

> console.log src/screens/Overview/index.tsx:66
>         accountId:  nodata
>
> console.log src/screens/Overview/index.tsx:64
>         location:  { pathname: '/mix/overview/nodata',
>           search: '',
>           hash: '',
>           state: undefined,
>           key: 'bn6zvv' }

// testing setup with wrapper as recommended in the [RTL docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router#reducing-boilerplate)

```
function renderWithProviders(
  ui,
  {
    route = '/',
    params = routes.root, 
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
  } = {},
  apolloMocks
) {
  console.log("route:", route) // see below
  console.log("params:", params) // see below
  return {
    ...render(
      <Provider store={mockProviderStore}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <MockedProvider mocks={apolloMocks}>
            <Route path={params}> // tried to set path to "params" not "route" so the slug of /url/:accountId is properly set
             {ui}
            </Route>
          </MockedProvider>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    ),
    history,
  };
}
```

the result of the console log in the test-utils file looks correct:

> console.log src/test-utils/index.js:19
>         route: /mix/overview/nodata
>
> console.log src/test-utils/index.js:20
>         params: /mix/overview/:accountId

// test itself

```
test('it works', async () => {
    const { findByText } = renderWithProviders(<Overview />, {
      route: routes.overview('1234567890'), // => path/1234567890
      params: routes.overview(), // => path/:accountId
    });

    await findByText('loading configs...');

    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => getByText('loading configs...'));

    await findByText('View your stuff now. It works!');
  });
```

I am trying the [recommended work around](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning) from #kentdodds to use `await` in the tests which lets state changes to settle correctly.

What is it about the React-Router hook which isn't picking up the route params correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure, even if you have a wrapper with Router/Route like suggested, that the component you want to test gets wrapped with a Route with params:

```
<Route path="/mix/config/:param1/:param2/:param3" >
  <Config />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 16):

You could also mock query parameters using Jest like so :

```
import ReactRouter from 'react-router'

describe(() => {
  test('...', () => {
    jest.spyOn(ReactRouter, 'useParams').mockReturnValue({ id: '1234' });
    // id = "1234" in your tested component
  });
});
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58180976/2295549 to mock more of react-router.

Comment: yeah, we did this originally...then I actually converted it to Typescript and the compiler got real angry about it, so I wanted to solve to use the built in functionality of the hook itself since the route is being passed as part of the test.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I'm also using Typescript. The advantage of using spyOn over mock is that the params can be different for each test in a test suite.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with named imports?