# React, Snapshot Test useParams undefined

Tags: reactjs, snapshot

I am trying to write a snapshot test in react for my component
In my component I have `useParams()`
While running the test it is returning an undefined error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

```
  20 |   const [value, setValue] = useState();
  21 |   const { show, changeDetails } = props;
> 22 |   const { id } = useParams();
     |                  ^
```

Component is at

```
  <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/myroute/:id"
        component={() => (
          <>
            <ModuleDetails />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
```

and test.js is like

```
it('renders correctly the assessment show page', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  history.push('/myroute/1');
  let tree = renderer
    .create(
      <Router history={history}>
        <ModuleDetails />
      </Router>
    )
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchInlineSnapsot(``);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test components using new react router hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117890/how-to-test-components-using-new-react-router-hooks)

Comment: I checked it and tried but test is not rendering properly

Comment: it('renders correctly', () => {
    let tree = renderer
    .create(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/myroute/1']}>
        <Route path="/myroute/:id">
          <ModuleDetails />
        </Route>
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchInlineSnapshot(``);
});

Answer (score 1):

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
 render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/myroute/1']}>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/myroute/:id"
          component={() => (
            <>
              <ModuleDetails />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </MemoryRouter>,
      container
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your component in `Router`, `useParams` uses something(probably history object) from Router context, no router - no context.

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing

And it was answered already [How to test components using new react router hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117890/how-to-test-components-using-new-react-router-hooks)

Comment: I am using route for my component.
And

let tree = renderer
    .create(
      <Router history={history}>
        <ModuleDetails />
      </Router>
    )
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchInlineSnapsot(``);

in my test.js

Comment: Not sure why you use `toJSON`, normally i used testing-library, it has snapshots.
https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/

At least try to select only component without a wrapper and take snapshot of it.

Comment: Possibly history.push is problematic, maybe try to use `initialEntries`.